# Google Analytics sandbox

Tags: google-analytics

I have some problems with the google analytics not working on production, I have made some fixes and used some plugins to check that the information sent to google is ok, but the problem is I cannot test properly on my sandbox since I do not have the credentials for the analytics account used on production instance. I will not have access to that account and I do not want to create a dummy account linked to my sandbox because I cannot have my sandbox address indexed by google. Is there any way to install a local server that emulates GA? Or a way to create a GA account and prevent it from indexing my sandbox address? I have found the urchin software that would have given me the possibility to install a local sandbox, but this was discontinued by google and I was not able to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "indexing" you mean "becoming a part of the Google search index an appearing in result pages",  that is not in any way related to analytics. If you have a problem that your pages Urls show up in GA (which really is the whole point of Analytics) you can programmatically pass dummy urls to the tracker:

```
ga('send', {
  'hitType': 'pageview',
  'page': '/home' // pass a virtual adress here per page
});
```

That way your sites structure will not be recognizable in GA (however this will make testing more difficult).

If at all possible you should have Google Tag Manager installed on the live page. GTM has a preview mode that allows you to directly in the live site without affecting other users (tags are only visible to visitors with the preview cookie).

As for emulating locally, no, not really. If you still use asynchronous tracking (ga.js) you can use  [setlocalGifPath](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiUrchin#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setLocalGifPath) and _setLocalServerMode to have the tracking data send to your own server, but that will not give you the interface - it just means you can create a log file with the google parameters that you have to parse yourself.

Universal Analytics does not (to my knowledge) have corresponding methods (they are a remnant from urchin days when people wanted to reprocess their data locally. As you've said urchin is now defunct and it would have been too expensive for a bit of local testing in any case).

Comment: I see, thank you for your answer, I have used google assistant but it is not concludent, for some reason it seems that it reports a fail on my local system, but it works for the same case on any other machine I have tested it. There is also GA debug, a chrome extension that shows the data sent to GA. Anyways what I want to make sure is that if set a null value for the page element my sandbox address will not be indexed by google bots. I knew about this trick, but what I look for is a confirmation that someone used it and the page did not got indexed by google bots. Thanks